# read multiple txt files then save each as xlsx file with same header for each

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been tasked with using a SAP custom reports that are given to me in a text file - sample below (removed names and made all values 0.00 for this sample). The task is to use this data and create xlsx files from this data. I have 100s of these txt files in a specific folder. How would I load this into python and create an xlsx file that saves the header data in same location/format above the table for each file?

I have the code below that creates the xlsx for each file but the format is all messed up. I need it in better format for each cell/column/row.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Current Code:

```
import glob
import os
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
filepath = 'mypath'
txtfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(filepath, '*z*.txt*'))

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for filename in txtfiles:
    readfiles = open(filename, 'r') 

    row_list = []

    for row in readfiles:
        row_list.append(row.split('\n'))

    column_list = zip(*row_list)

    workbook = Workbook(filename.replace('.txt', '.xlsx'))
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

    i = 0
    for column in column_list:
        for item in range(len(column)):
            value = column[item].strip()
            if is_number(value):
                worksheet.write(item, i, float(value))
            else:
                worksheet.write(item, i, value)
        i += 1
    workbook.close()
```

Sample report below:

```
                                                 SAMPLE REPORT TEMPLATE

Page Number:  1 of   1                                                                         Time of Output:06:37:00
Author of Report:ME                                                                            Date of Output:09/27/2018
Ledger:SAMPLE                                                                                  Version: 1
Currency: USD                                                                                  Fiscal Year:2018
Report Group:RANDOM                                                                            Period:  0 to   10

|.                                                           |    Outside MONEY    | Outside MONEY2      |    Outside MONEY3   |   Subtotal MONIES   |
|------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|   INCOME MONIES BEFORE CERTAIN CALCULATIONS SAMPLE         |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|------------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|   1 - Line Data 1                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   1 - Line Data 2                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   1 - Line Data 3                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   1 - Line Data 4                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   1 - Line Data 5                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   2 - Line Data 1                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   2 - Line Data 2                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   2 - Line Data 3                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|*  Sample Random Line W/ Star                               |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 1                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 2                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 3                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 4                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 5                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 6                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 7                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
|   3 - Line Data 8                                          |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |                0.00 |
```

Comment: Yes it's relatively easy to read the txt file line by line and collect the data in a python list or dictionary. No need to use pandas for that. You can then use the XlsxWriter (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) to write them as excel. Try it and post the code you have if you need more help.

Comment: @576i Would you just use readlines() or list? Sorry, I have never done anything like this as I typically use files easily uploaded as tables into dataframes.

Comment: with open ('filename') as f1:  for line in f1: do something with line... -

Answer (score 1):

Reading from a text file and add each line as an item to a list can be done as follows:

```
lines = []
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as textinputfile:
    for readline in textinputfile:
        lines.append(readline)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your text report fields are of a fixed length, you could extract the header with one function and the data with another one. So, in your sample each row of data is 151 characters. Since the header is much shorter, you can easily know if the row in the current loop is from the header or it is data.

I would suggest to split the row by ':' if it is header and by '|' if it is data. By the end of the loop, you will have each row with the fields properly separated.

If you have further trouble with managing the data, or you need more detail, I suggest regex module.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I should have specified in my post that the file is only a sample and each txt file is different lengths. For sake of posting an example it just made it easier to post of that length.

Comment: Well, if they are large enough, you can use the same logic. Let's say the header never is larger than 100 characters and the data always is; you could use that logic.

Comment: Or also you could split everything by '|' and the rows with only one field will be the header. Those you can treat afterwards.